# How to be connected to two seperate wireguard networks

Tags: wireguard

I wanted to access my home router from anywhere without it being on a public address so I installed wireguard on it, installed wireguard on a digital ocean server, installed wireguard on my own laptop and set it up so I can access the router from my laptop through the public server. This all works fine, the server is 10.8.0.1, laptop is 10.8.0.2, router is 10.8.0.3.

Now I want to repeat this but with completely seperate work stuff. It will be my laptop but a different server in the middle and a different router.
So I thought I'll just repeat this all but use 10.7.0.1/10.7.0.2/10.7.0.3 but obviously this doesn't work because my laptop is only listening on 10.8.0.2:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.8.0.2/24
```

How can I make it also join the 10.7.0.1 network or am I doing something completely stupid and misunderstanding the whole thing? Should I actually just be making the second server 10.8.0.4 or something?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just needed two interfaces, using wg-work.conf and wg-home.conf, and actually 10.8.1.1 is better for the second server.